# How to parse SimpleXMLElement in php / Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, xmlhttprequest, simplexml, guzzle

I use Guzzle to make an XML request to an external API in the back-end.

This is where I create the Guzzle client:

```
$client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
```

This is where I make the request:

```
$request = $client->request( 'GET', 'This is where I put the URL');
```

This is where I get the Guzzle response and try to parse it:

```
$xml = $request->getBody()->getContents();
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

If I do this:

```
dd($xml);
```

I receive this in return:

```
SimpleXMLElement {#240 ▼
  +"StatusCode": "1"
  +"StatusDescription": "Duplicated request"
  +"MerchantId": "***"
  +"Company": "***"
  +"CompanyCity": "***"
  +"CompanyPhone": "***"
  +"CompanyDbaName": "***"
  +"Balance": "99965"
  +"TransDate": "2017-10-07"
  +"TransTime": "06:58:48"
  +"ProductVer": "***"
  +"PromoVer": object
  +"SoftVer": object
  +"InvoiceNumber": object
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to parse this. I want to get the `1` in `StatusCode`.

If I do this:

```
dd($xml->StatusCode);
```

I receive this:

```
SimpleXMLElement {#242 ▼
  +0: "1"
}
```

How do I get just `1` ?

Comment: `$xml->StatusCode` is still an object. You can cast it to string in various ways, for example simply `echo $xml->StatusCode`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: I submitted an answer with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `var_dump()` output is correct. `$xml->StatusCode` is a `SimpleXMLElement` instance. This is of course needed in case you have to, for example, add a child element to it:

```
$xml->StatusCode->addChild("test", "value");
```

If `$xml->StatusCode` contained only the value of the element rather than an instance of `SimpleXMLElement`, you wouldn't be able to do any modifications on the loaded XML.

So, what you need to do, is cast the value of `StatusCode` to a string. There are various ways of doing this:

```
var_dump($xml->StatusCode); // returns SimpleXMLElement instance
var_dump((string)$xml->StatusCode); // explicitly
var_dump($xml->StatusCode->__toString()); // explicitly, calling the magic function
echo $xml->StatusCode; // implicitly
```

[Some demos](https://3v4l.org/A3AeA)

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * @param $xmlObject
 * @param array $out
 * @return array
 */
private function simpleXmlToArray($xmlObject, $out = array ())
{
    foreach ($xmlObject as $index => $node ){
        if(count($node) === 0){
            $out[$node->getName()] = $node->__toString ();
        }else{
            $out[$node->getName()][] = $this->simpleXmlToArray($node);
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```