# Get string XML node value as string in laravel / PHP

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I got an XML response from server. This is the response.

```
<response>
     <response_code>Success</response_code>
</response>
```

I stored this response in a variable `$response`. There is another similar response for failure. So, I just want to check if the node value is `Success` or `Failure`.

What I do is this:

```
$xmlString =simplexml_load_string($response) or die("Error: Cannot create object"); 

$resp_code =  (string)$xmlString->response_code;

if($resp_code == 'Success'){
  echo 'Successfully completed';
}
else{
  echo 'not done';
}
```

But the if condition doesn't work. I guess the `$resp_code` is not string here.

I also tried `$xmlString->response_code->__toString();` but didn't work. 
What am I missing? Somebody please help.

P.S: I'm doing this in Laravel, if that helps.

Comment: Tried using 'SimpleXMLElement($response)' but Laravel throws error- cannot find the function.

Comment: did you try  this [link ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620096/how-to-parse-simplexmlelement-in-php-laravel-5)

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? What have you tried to debug the problem? If something is not working (like you've written in the first comment), explain that exactly. Additionally, do not place such information in the comment section; rather edit your question

Answer (score 1):

After testing your code, its works perfectly.

The `simplexml_load_string()` function parses the given response as an object and by using type casting, your output is definitely a string.

If you keep getting results other than a success, its probably because the response the server is giving you isn't a success, or there might be a mix in the use of uppercase and lowercase alphabet.

Try editing this part of your code

```
if(strtolower($resp_code) == 'success'){
  echo 'Successfully completed';
} else{
  echo 'not done';
}
```

That should take of any mix up of such nature.

Comment: When I do `echo $response`, I can see the response is success. It gives the same xml that I gave above. When I `echo $resp_code`, I get only `Success` but the `if($resp_code == 'Success' )` doesn't return true. I tried lowering the case but didn't help.

Comment: Figured it out. the response was actually ' Success ' with spaces not 'Success'. Used trim and it worked. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

If you would like to get away from PHP's pretty convoluted xml handling, you can use my package:

https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array

```
$xmlArray = xml_to_array($response);

$resp_code =  $xmlArray['response_code'];

if($resp_code == 'Success'){
  echo 'Successfully completed';
}
else{
  echo 'not done';
}
```